# Find pixel position of point in highstock chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Hi so my requirement goes like below

I am using highstock chart and want to draw a rectangle covering to timestamps that satisfy some condition .

My logic is as below .:
1. Find the index of the required timestamps in chart.series[0].points.
2. If index of both points are found then draw rectangle with pixel position

```
var x1 = chart.series[0].points[positionPoint1].plotX;
var x2 = chart.series[0].points[positionPoint2].plotX;
```

Now what I have found on highstock chart is it does'nt show the complete points in `chart.series[0].points` but just shows the group points here.

All points are shown in `chart.series[0].xData;` but it does'nt contain the pixels poisitions . My question is how can I get pixel postion of any point in **highstock** chart irrespective of whether it is grouped or not ?

Answer (score 4):

Having value of point, you can convert to pixels by [toPixels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels) function in axis.

Comment: can you please write some code for me .. I think it will also work for grouped points

Comment: In the documentation, you have a example how to use that.